# Hebrew field in text file issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am trying to import a txt file which has Hebrew customer names into a SQL Server Database, and for that NAME to be displayed in Hebrew for that COLUMN only.

I know how to insert it with this special insert statement below which works . If only I could grab that field from the txt file in Hebrew in SSIS .

```
create table #temp ( str Nvarchar(100) ) ;

insert into #temp(str)values(N'HEBREW SAMPLE IN HERE') ;

select * from #temp ;

drop table #temp;
```

The problem with SSIS is that all the import tasks put the Hebrew customer name in some junk format and I cant do anything then. Current collation on server, database, tables columns is ;

```
1. SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2. SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3. SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Answer (score 0):

Chane your database to HEBREW_CI_AS instead. You can do that at your database options for each database.

Choose property menu, then select options. First pulldown you can select sorter.

Comment: Just tested this suggestion and it does not work . Sorry . Think we need to chnage how SSIS is reading in the HEBREW field somehow .

Comment: Does you SSIS task setup the connection to the database via ole db? First try to enter some hebrew content via copy/paste in the database after you changed it and check if it stores correctly. After you can take a close task to the SSIS project with your Visual Studio